# How can I synchronize a has_many association using accepts_nested_attributes_for by foreign_key instead of ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I would like to synchronize a has_many association by foreign key.  It seems I have to write custom code to do this.  Is there any Rails / Active Record magic / Gem to achieve this?  Specifically, I'd like to synchronize a join-table where the pairs of foreign keys should be unique.

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_tags, :dependent=>:destroy, :inverse_of => :food
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_tags, :allow_destroy => true
end

class FoodTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag, :inverse_of=>:food_tags
  belongs_to :food, :inverse_of=>:food_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_tags, :dependent=>:destroy, :inverse_of=>:tag
  has_many :foods, :through=>:food_tags
end
```

For my form with nested attributes (or my JSON API), I'd really like to omit the FoodTag id and use the tag_id to synchronize when updating a food.

I want to submit this on update to show that the tag is set or cleared

```
# this one is set
food[food_tag_attributes][0][tag_id]   = 2114
food[food_tag_attributes][0][_destroy] = false

# this one is cleared
food[food_tag_attributes][1][tag_id]   = 2116
food[food_tag_attributes][1][_destroy] = true
```

Instead, I have to submit this for update:

```
# this one is set
food[food_tag_attributes][0][id]       = 109293
food[food_tag_attributes][0][tag_id]   = 2114
food[food_tag_attributes][0][_destroy] = false

# this one is cleared
food[food_tag_attributes][0][id]       = 109294
food[food_tag_attributes][1][tag_id]   = 2116
food[food_tag_attributes][1][_destroy] = true
```

This pushes a burden to the client to know the IDs of the food tag records instead of just being able to Set or Clear tags based on the tag id.

Can this be done easily?  I'm sure I could write a before_save filter on Food, but it seems like there should be a reasonably generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called index: for fields_for in the view helper. You can set the index as your foreign_key. Then instead of sequential or some arbitrary numbers, your foreign_key will be used as the key to refer to your object.

**EDIT:**

`<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
      <%= person_form.text_field :name %>
      <% @person.addresses.each do |address| %>
        <%= person_form.fields_for address, **index**: address.id do |address_form|%>
          <%= address_form.text_field :city %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>`

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: It is available in the rails form helper guide. I have provided the code in the edited answer. There is an index option in fields_for.